# Cannot find a solid solution to odds

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm making something where a players gains credits over the level they currently have.

Now let's say on average I want to spend the amount of credits equal to the players level, meaning if he is level one he on average wins 1 credit, and if he is level 50 he will on average win 50.

Now what I've done is create a method to calculate different outcomes using the following function,

```
var getDailyRewards = function(level){
    var averagePayment = 0.01 * level,
            paymentIncrement = 3.00
            paymentDivision = 4,
            paymentAmount = 8;

    var allPayments = [];

    for(x = 1; x < (paymentAmount + 1); x++){
        var payment = (averagePayment / paymentDivision) * Math.pow(x, paymentIncrement);
        console.log(payment);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0.25
2
6.75
16
...
```

How can I link this to a percentage? from [0, 100]? I can't just divide payment by averagePayment as it would not work with numbers under one.

Comment: `getDailyRewards(level) / getDailyRewards(100) * 100`

Comment: @JonasW. I'd like everything to be in a single function, or at least the chance calculation and amount the player will receive. I'd like this function to output an array eventually with the chance of a certain reward and the amount the reward contains.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit - what is the percentage you are trying to link to? What output would you want to see exactly, say for level 50?

Comment: @Stuart Okay let's say I'm making a daily login bonus where I give the people random bonus' based on their levels. I calculate the random bonus' and now I want to link it to a percentage. Percentage should be linked to the average paid in credits which is the players level times 0.01. Let's say if 100 players who login all have level 10 they should on average have received 0.01*10*100

Comment: Still not clear at all what you are looking for - could you edit your question with an example of what output you want to see for a given input? There are lots of ways to get a random bonus averaging say 100 (e.g. `Math.random() * 200` or `Math.random() * 50 + 75`) but it depends what distribution of bonuses you are looking for and how all this relates to your existing function.